# Eclipse Include Paths outside Project Directory

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt

I am having an issue including files outside my project directory. I have a project in eclipse with some header files outside of the project that need to be linked to my project. I have added the path to C/C++ General for the header files and included them in my code. It seems like only one of the files can be seen and the other file I am getting an unresolved inclusion error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You should set correct path. Notice that this path should be either absolute, or relative to build dir (that is realative to `<your_project_dir_name>/Debug` or `<your_project_dir_name>/Release`)

Comment: Could you explain what that means? My project is in the folder C:/Kay/Arend/ground/cfl/tempSensor and I want to access the file available in the entire Arend folder. What would my path be?

Comment: There are two places define include paths in C/C++ General: "Paths and Symbols", and "Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc.". Did you try both? I sometimes find that adding it to "Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros, etc." is not effective, but adding it to "Paths and Symbols" works.

Comment: `../../../../` it should be set at C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes -> Include paths for all project configurations (which can be selected on top of that page) .

Comment: I have added it to both "Paths and Symbols" and "Preprocessor Include..." and that does not work. I still get a fatal error: no such file or directory. Is there any reason that this would not work?

Answer (score 0):

The following is thanks to comments from @user7860670 -- you can see more commentary in [eclipse: including a path outside of the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72661819/eclipse-including-a-path-outside-of-the-project/)

Short form:

Use system variables.

For include directories relative to your *workspace*, use something of the form `"${workspace_loc}/../my_includes"`.

For include directories relative to your *project*, use something of the form `"${project_loc}/../my_includes"`.

Note that in some IDEs, the system variables may be named differently.

See  [eclipse: including a path outside of the project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72661819/eclipse-including-a-path-outside-of-the-project/) for more details.