# eclipse: including a path outside of the project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Note: This is a follow-on question to the unanswered [Eclipse Include Paths outside Project Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46321940/eclipse-include-paths-outside-project-directory), albeit with considerably more information.

In Eclipse, I want to add an include path that is adjacent to my Eclipse project directory.  And for portability, I need the include path to be relative, not absolute.  In this specific case, I'm using MCUExpresso 11.5.1 (built on Eclipse CDT 10.3.3), but I've observed this in other Eclipse variants.

### Setup

For the following, I have a folder `my_includes/` which is at the same level as my Eclipse folder, `frdm_k64f/':

```
  frdm_k64f/
    .settings/
    CMSIS/
    ...
  my_includes/
    foo.h
```

I want `my_includes/` to be on the compiler include path, but as a relative path, not absolute.

### What I've tried

#### Attempt 1

In Projects => Properties => C/C++ Build => Settings => MCU C Compiler => Includes, I added the line `"${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/../my_includes}"` so the entire -I list looks like this:
[image]
But this fails: At compile time, the "/../my_includes" entry I added has vanished from the -I list.  Here's what's on the command line:

```
...
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\board" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\source" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\drivers" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\utilities" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\component\serial_manager" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\component\uart" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\component\lists" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\device" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\CMSIS" 
-O0 -fno-common -g3 -Wall ...
```

#### Attempt #2

When I specify an absolute path, it works:
[image]

```
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\board" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\source" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\drivers" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\utilities" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\component\serial_manager" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\component\uart" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\component\lists" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\device" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\CMSIS" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\my_includes" 
-O0 -fno-common -g3 -Wall ...
```

... but as I mentioned, for portability, an absolute path isn't a viable option.

#### Attempt #3

Following a suggestion from @user7860670, I tried just `"${workspace_loc}/my_includes"`, but that expands into the workspace directory, not the project directory:

```
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\board" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\source" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\drivers" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\utilities" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\component\serial_manager" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\component\uart" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\component\lists" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\device" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\CMSIS" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Documents\MCUXpressoIDE_11.5.1_7266\workspace/my_includes" 
-O0 -fno-common -g3 -Wall -c -ffunction-sections ...
```

#### Attempt #4 (success):

Following a second suggestion from @user7860670, I tried `"../../my_includes"`, and despite being somewhat non-idiomatic, it works!  It expands into the desired -I directory:

```
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\board" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\source" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\drivers" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\utilities" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\component\serial_manager" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\component\uart" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\component\lists" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\device" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\CMSIS" 
-I"../../my_includes" 
-O0 -fno-common ...
```

#### Attempt #5 (better solution):

Now that I grok the , the right approach appears to be to use the `ProjDirPath` system variable, as in `"${ProjDirPath}/../my_includes"`, which expands to:

```
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\board" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\source" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\drivers" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\utilities" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\component\serial_manager" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\component\uart" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\component\lists" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\device" 
-I"C:\Users\r\Projects\mulib-examples\examples\test_stdbsp\frdm_k64f\CMSIS" 
-I"C:/Users/r/Projects/mulib-examples/examples/test_stdbsp/frdm_k64f/../my_includes" 
-O0 -fno-common -g3 -Wall ...
```

### The question (redux):

How can I specify an include path that's outside of the Eclipse project using a relative path?

Comment: For portability, what makes a path relative to the workspace's location, but outside of it, viable?

Comment: @nitind: that's a fair question.  In this case, the adjacent directory is distributed with the project itself.  (And the adjacent directory is shared among multiple projects, so it can't live inside any one of the projects.)

Comment: `${workspace_loc}` works like shell substitution. So it should be `"${workspace_loc}/my_includes"`, and another (lazy) way is to use relative (to build folder) path `../../my_includes`

Comment: @user7860670: Your second suggestion works -- see edited OP above.  If you'd care to give a short answer, I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: @user7860670: Even better, suggest an answer that uses `ProdDirPath` (see latest edit) and I'll still mark it as your solution.

Comment: I'm not sure, but `${workspace_loc}` not working is probably something MCUExpresso-specific. `${workspace_loc}` certainly works with vanilla Eclipse CDT. It also has `${project_loc}` available instead of `ProjDirPath`.

Comment: @user7860670 The fact that `${workspace_loc}` doesn't work makes sense in this case: my _project_ directory is not inside my _workspace_ directory.  I'll try it in Simplicity Studio as well and will check on `${project_loc}`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the pointers from @user7860670:

Use **system variables**, which you can find listed here (don't forget to click the "Show system variables" box):

[image]

### If the included directory is relative to your *workspace*:

Use something of the form `"${workspace_loc}/../my_includes"`

### If the included directory is relative to your *project*:

In  something of the form `"${project_loc}/../my_includes"`

Note that in some Eclipse-based IDEs, the system variable name might be different.  For example, in MCUExpresso, this would be `"${ProjDirPath}/../my_includes"`